# How can GLKit draw triangles using both CW or CCW notation?

Tags: opengl-es, glkit

I have a simple textured quad (composed of 2 triangles) that im rendering in my iPhone app using GLKit.

Now for some reason I am not seeing any difference when defining my vertices with CW notation vs CCW notation. Why is this? Note that I am using the default GLKit project template with minimal changes. Also, I am using the GLKBaseEffect for rendering, not ES2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quad, CW vs CCW changes the normal -- which side of the triangles is "up". [Facet culling](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCullFace.xml) is disabled by default (use `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)` to enable it), so both the "up" or the "down" triangles will be rendered.

Comment: This is becoming quite frustrating. i took the GLKit project template, reduced all the sample vertices so that it renders just one face (a quad). Yet i still cant get the CW/CCW to make a difference. I tried GL_FRONT, GL_BACK, and GL_FRONT_AND_BACK as parameters to the glCullFace. Nothing works. I see my polygons all the time.

Comment: Ok. Now I am able to see the difference. I had to call glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)!!

Comment: Woops, should have mentioned that. Glad you got it working :)